# python create a list combined with an append

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to do something like:

```
([0.01]*9).append(0.91)
```

to get to:

```
[0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, ...., 0.91]
```

Is there a way to do this in one line rather than:

```
temp = [0.01]*9
temp = temp.append(0.91)
```

Comment: `[0.01]*9+[0.91]`?

Comment: Furthermore `temp = temp.append(..)` will result in `temp` being `None`, since `append` works **inplace**.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Thank you! Coming from the R world it's always the simplest things that trip you up!

Comment: well that holds with most things in life :) since people *underestimate* them :). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate to the list

```
 temp = [0.01]*9 + [0.91]
```